# When is a backing field generated in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Quoting Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-properties) on *'Backing properties'.*

> A backing field will be generated for a property if it uses the default implementation of at least one of the accessors, or if a custom accessor references it through the `field` identifier.
>
> For example, there would be no backing field in the following case:
>
> ```kotlin
> val isEmpty: Boolean
>    get() = this.size == 0
> ```

At least one of the accessors (setter) is using the default implementation, then why would there be no backing field in the above case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At least one of the accessors (setter) is using the default implementation

The example property is a `val`, so there is no setter. The only accessor is the getter, and that one doesn't use the default implementation, so no backing field.

I agree it would have been clearer if they started with a `var` example, but this example is definitely worth noting to clarify how it works for `val`s.